# Combo box flickering in Window 10 Touch screen

Tags: wpf, combobox, windows-10, touch, flicker

I am using a  WPF Combobox in my Wpf application.
Following are my issue scenario:
1.Open  combo box using touch
2.Touch on any item from drop down list
3.Combo box drop down list close after a flickering.
This issue is not  there in mouse click.
I made AllowsTransparency="True" for windows

System Specification:
1.Windows 10
2.Visual Studio 2017
3.Unchecked "Enable press and  hold for right clicking" in Pen and Touch setting

Following is my Xaml.code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="cb" Height="50" Width="50">
            <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>C</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>D</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>E</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>F</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>G</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please help

Comment: Could you show us what you have been trying to do so far?

Comment: @ Dima Kozhevin I added few more descriptions for it .Please check

Comment: @Dima any updates